# Parsing Json responses in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, mediawiki

I have the following json returned by mediawiki.

```
{
    "query-continue": {
        "allcategories": {
            "accontinue": "SB_Canto_09_Verses_Appearing_in_CC"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "allcategories": [{
            "*": "S"
        }, {
            "*": "SAY"
        }, {
            "*": "SB Canto 01 Verses Appearing in CC"
        }, {
            "*": "SB Canto 02 Verses Appearing in CC"
        }, {
            "*": "SB Canto 03 Verses Appearing in CC"
        }, {
            "*": "SB Canto 04 Verses Appearing in CC"
        }, {
            "*": "SB Canto 05 Verses Appearing in CC"
        }, {
            "*": "SB Canto 06 Verses Appearing in CC"
        }, {
            "*": "SB Canto 07 Verses Appearing in CC"
        }, {
            "*": "SB Canto 08 Verses Appearing in CC"
        }]
    }
}
```

The data i want to extract in a list is

```
S

SAY

SB Canto 01 Verses Appearing in CC

SB Canto 02 Verses Appearing in CC

SB Canto 03 Verses Appearing in CC

..
```

and so on.

I have the following code

```
$.ajax({
    url: newurl,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        //How do I access the elements? Since they are identified as "*"
        // I tried
        console.log(result.query.allcategories[0].*);
        //but it does not work
        //but the following apparently gives some output
        console.log(result.query.allcategories[0]);
        /*
returns 
Object {*: "S"} using%20ajax.html:62
Object {*: "S"} using%20ajax.html:62
Object {*: "S"} using%20ajax.html:62
*/
    });
});
```

I need to access the elements and have them displayed as a list on my page. I am not able to understand how to do this!

also using

console.log(result.query.allcategories['*'][0]); or

console.log(result.query.allcategories[0]['*']);

does not work out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I guess JavaScript doesn't like very much the `[0].*` part.
I suggest you try `console.log(result.query.allcategories[0]['*'];` instead, but if possible, change the name of the key in your object to an actual word.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, niether console.log(result.query.allcategories[0]['*']; nor console.log(result.query.allcategories['*'][0];

Comment: console.log(result.query.allcategories[0]["*"];

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/n4C5d/

Answer (score 0):

You can't return from ajax. Plus if your url isn't stored locally you wont access your json file you might need to look at jsonp.

You are using Ajax incorrectly, the idea is not to have it return anything, but instead hand off the data to something called a callback function, which handles the data.

IE:

```
function handleData( responseData ) {
    // do what you want with the data
    console.log(responseData);
}

$.ajax({
    url: "hi.php",
    ...
    success: function ( data, status, XHR ) {
        handleData(data);
    }
});
```

returning anything in the submit handler will not do anything, you must instead either hand off the data, or do what you want with it directly inside the success function.

Comment: How do you know the url isn't local? Where is he returning anything? I don't even see the `return` keyword in the snippet. He's able to log the object he wants, he just needs to know how to access the property named `*`.